# Any example of using https:inbound-endpoint of mule?

Tags: mule

I wanted to use mule ESB to access a rest api periodically, and save the response JSON to disk.

Basically, I need to use https:inbound-endpoint to perform something like:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXX" -k https://somehost.com/api
```

in mule.

Any working example for me to start with?

Comment: Just to be sure: you're question is just about HTTPS, not dealing with the Bearer authorization header?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to configure the https connector and create a keystore or use the one on the JDK.

The [mule documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/33X/HTTPS+Transport+Reference) page contains a very simple example with step-by-step settings.